# Fetch multiple checkbox values from a form

Tags: python, django

I am developing a webapp which displays checkboxes for tasks. On selecting the task and submitting, the task description is showed. However, the code I have written shows only for one and not multiple. Kindly help me out.
Below is my code

Here is my **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^view_task_description/$', views.view_task_description, name='view_task_description'),
url(r'^view_task_description/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.get_task_description, name="get_task_description"),
```

Here is my **views.py**:

```
@login_required
def view_task_description(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        task_description = GetTaskDescription(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if task_description.is_valid():
            obj = GetTaskDescription.get_task_description(task_description)
            return redirect('get_task_description', pk=obj[0].pk)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/select_task_description.html', context={'view_tasks': GetTaskDescription(user=request.user)})


@login_required
def get_task_description(request, pk):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'todoapp/task_desc.html', context={'description': obj.description})
```

Here is my **forms.py**:

```
class GetTaskDescription(forms.Form):

    get_tasks = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Task.objects.none(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(GetTaskDescription, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['get_tasks'].queryset = self.user.task_set.all()

    def get_task_description(self):
        tasks = self.cleaned_data['get_tasks']
        return tasks
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug task_description.cleaned_fields['get_tasks'] in the view after `task_description.is_valid()`?
Could you share the template code?  
NB You have defined get_task_description in the GetTaskDescription so why you are not accessing it via the form's instance? You could just call `task_description.get_task_description() `.

Comment: @KristiyanGospodinov I am calling that method from my view. Have a look again at the code.

Comment: Yes, you are calling it but instead of using the form's instance(`task_description. get_task_description()`) you are calling the class' method and pass the form's instance. This is not a good way to do it. After that you are redirecting and you pass only the first choice pk to the view. Thats way it ' shows only for one and not multiple'.

Comment: @KristiyanGospodinov so how do I do it ? What is the correct way of doing it ?